# Temp table dropping immediately after query finishes

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

[image: Temp Table sql code]

If I highlight then execute lines 1-4, I get output

> Commands completed successfully.

Then, if I highlight and execute lines 6-14, I get output message

> Invalid object name '#TestThis'

If I highlight and execute lines 1 - 16, I can see the one row of data returned. Why would a temp table that was just created (in the same session) immediately be dropped/invalid right after the code was executed?  We're running this on an Azure based SQL Server.

Comment: What version or compatibility level is your DB? I just ran this on Azure SQL Server 2014 (120) and it worked as expected.

Comment: Temp tables don't stay around....try highlighting them all

Comment: I run the same code in my SSMS 17.9, my Azure SQL database is V12, compatibility_level is 140, everything works ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the cause of this issue was using MFA instead of Active Directory password.  Once the connection was switched to Active Directory password, the temp tables were created and accessible and persisted as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If the session remains alive, the temporary table should still exist and be accessible. Make sure you are executing the create statement and the other ones on the same session and you are not getting a disconnection message in between.

Make sure you have the "**Disconnect after the query executes**" check in SSMS **OFF**.

[image]

If it still fails, do this check:

- Create your temporary table, and keep the session alive (don't close the tab or disconnect it):

  ```
  CREATE TABLE #TestThis (oldvalue INT, newvalue INT)
  ```
- On a different session, query `tempdb` like the following:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE [name] LIKE N'#TestThis%'
  ```

You should be able to see the temporary table created on the other session, starting with the same name and getting a bunch of underscores and some numbers at the end. This means the table still exists and you should be able to access it from the original session.

[image]

If you open a 3rd session and create the same temporary table, 2 of these should be listed on the `tempdb` query:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your answer came the closest to understanding what the issue was and a possible solution.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Matthew Walk You can try this solution as I showed in the example below.

```
CREATE TABLE #TestThis(oldvalue INT, newvalue INT )

INSERT INTO  #TestThis(oldvalue, newvalue) VALUES (1,3),(5,7)

select  oldvalue, newvalue FROM  #TestThis

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestThis') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestThis
```

In this example you need to check object id is **null or not** for your temptable, if it is not null then you need to **drop** your temp table.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

A session is created every time you click the execute icon, so yes, if you don’t highlight the “create table” part, the table wouldn’t exist.

You can either remove the hash (#) in front of the table name if you want the table to stay in the db until you drop it .... or also highlight the create table part every time you click “execute” ....whichever fits your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

"#Temp" table is session level. If the database connection or session closed, the object "#TestThis" will be deleted.

You must keep the session going.

You should first highlight execute lines 1-4 to create the temp table "#TestThis" if not exist.

```
  CREATE TABLE #TestThis
  (
   oldvalue INTEGER,
   newvalue INTEGER)
```

Then you can execute lines 6-14. If you don't first create the temp table, how can you insert the data to temp table "#TestThis"?

Now you can execute:

```
INSERT INTO #TestThis
 (
    oldvalue,
    newvalue
   )
 VALUES
 (  1234,
    7788
    )
```

Or

```
 SELECT * FROM #TempThis
```

Hope this helps.